# Getting the body of POST request(Amazon SNS ) in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, post, amazon-sns

I am trying to get the body of an Amazon SNS request but it is returned as an object. I can get the headers from the request without any problems. (req.header('x-amz-sns-message-type'))

```
var msgBody = req.body.Message;
```

The msgBody variable is returned as an object where I expect to get the string value from the request.

I am using express and body-parser with the following options:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

The request format is as follows (shortened for easy reading):

```
POST /createLog/slackLogSNS/ HTTP/1.1
x-amz-sns-message-type: Notification
x-amz-sns-message-id: 3f71e0db-a9b1-5092-96f4-b26015676ba0

{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "3f71e0db-a9b1-5092-96f4-b26015676ba0",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:043886476179:testslackSNS",
  "Subject" : "hghghgfhgfhg",
  "Message" : "{\n  \"Type\" : \"Notification\",\n  \"MessageId\" : \"22b80b92-fdea-4c2c-8f9d-bdfb0c7bf324\",\n  \"TopicArn\" : \"arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic\",\n  \"Subject\" : \"My First Message\",\n  \"Message\" : \"Hello world!\",\n  \"Timestamp\" : \"2012-05-02T00:54:06.655Z\",\n  \"SignatureVersion\" : \"1\",\n  \"Signature\" : \"EXAMPLEw6JRNwm1LFQL4ICB0bnXrdB8ClRMTQFGBqwLpGbM78tJ4etTwC5zU7O3tS6tGpey3ejedNdOJ+1fkIp9F2/LmNVKb5aFlYq+9rk9ZiPph5YlLmWsDcyC5T+Sy9/umic5S0UQc2PEtgdpVBahwNOdMW4JPwk0kAJJztnc=\",\n  \"SigningCertURL\" : \"https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem\",\n  \"UnsubscribeURL\" : \"https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic:c9135db0-26c4-47ec-8998-413945fb5a96\"\n}",

  }
}
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(typeof req.body.Message)`?

Answer (score 3):

`console.log("stringified json")` will parse the JSON string before printing it to the console. However if you check the `typeof req.body.Message` you'll see it as string type as expected.

`console.log(typeof req.body.Message)`

It's the console.log() method doing the conversion behind the seen.

if you need you could use `JSON.stringify({your json object})` to get a stringified version of the objects.

Below is the code(index.js) to simulate your case with the provided request payload in the question.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing

app.post('/',  function(req, res) {
  // get posts
  console.log(req.body);
  var x = req.body.Message;
  console.log(typeof req.body.Message) // string
  console.log(x.Type) // undefined
  res.json({"a" : "test response"})
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Message" that you are looking for is part of the stringified JSON in your request.

You should be able to access it using...

```
const msgBody = JSON.parse(req.body.Message).Message;
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives me "unexpected token u in json at position 0". req itself is definitely defined since I can access the headers.

Comment: What's in `req.body`?

Comment: there is an object. it gives object{} when console logged.

Comment: @CodeBunny log the req.body with console.dir(req.body)

Answer (score 0):

I've pulled the object from the question above. The only JSON string to be parsed is `Message` inside of the object. `req.body` is already an object. If `req.body` were a JSON string, you would see `'` or `"` to begin and end the variable's value.

```js
const obj = {
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "3f71e0db-a9b1-5092-96f4-b26015676ba0",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:043886476179:testslackSNS",
  "Subject" : "hghghgfhgfhg",
  "Message" : "{\n  \"Type\" : \"Notification\",\n  \"MessageId\" : \"22b80b92-fdea-4c2c-8f9d-bdfb0c7bf324\",\n  \"TopicArn\" : \"arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic\",\n  \"Subject\" : \"My First Message\",\n  \"Message\" : \"Hello world!\",\n  \"Timestamp\" : \"2012-05-02T00:54:06.655Z\",\n  \"SignatureVersion\" : \"1\",\n  \"Signature\" : \"EXAMPLEw6JRNwm1LFQL4ICB0bnXrdB8ClRMTQFGBqwLpGbM78tJ4etTwC5zU7O3tS6tGpey3ejedNdOJ+1fkIp9F2/LmNVKb5aFlYq+9rk9ZiPph5YlLmWsDcyC5T+Sy9/umic5S0UQc2PEtgdpVBahwNOdMW4JPwk0kAJJztnc=\",\n  \"SigningCertURL\" : \"https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-f3ecfb7224c7233fe7bb5f59f96de52f.pem\",\n  \"UnsubscribeURL\" : \"https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:MyTopic:c9135db0-26c4-47ec-8998-413945fb5a96\"\n}",
}

console.log(typeof obj); // 'object'

// obj is not a JSON string, but rather a recognized object
// therefore, JSON.parse(obj) will return an error

console.log(typeof obj.Message); // 'string'

const message = JSON.parse(obj.Message) // converts the Message JSON string into an object

console.log(typeof message) // 'object'
console.log(message);
```